# How to view timestamp when pipe finished copying data from stage to table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've created a Pipe from an S3 stage and with a python script I'm generating the timestamps of when I am generating the data from a streaming service into file batches. I would also like to be able to add the timestamp when the files were actually copied into the table from the S3 stage. I've found some documentation regarding the `PIPE_USAGE_HISTORY` method but although I've already ran for the past days quite a few tests the below returns an empty table. What am I doing wrong?

```
select * from table(information_schema.pipe_usage_history(
    date_range_start=>dateadd('day',-14,current_date()),
    date_range_end=>current_date())
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. There is another query I should be using: `copy_history`
The above query would be rewritten as follows

```
select * from table(information_schema.copy_history(
  table_name => '{replace with your schema.table}',
  start_time => dateadd(days, -14, current_timestamp()),
  end_time => current_timestamp())
)
```